# How do I update my branch in git?

Tags: git

(1) I fork a person's repo in Github, let's call the person's repo as remoteRepo, my github's repo as myRepo.
(2) I clone it to my local pc.
I use this command,

```
$git clone [remoteRepo] -b [branch_name] /my/local/folder
```

Now,the remoteRepo has changed. I am going to update my local files in order to keep same source code with his.

I did like this,

```
$ git remote add upstream [remoteRepo]
$ git fetch upstream
$ git fetch upstream 
$ git merge upstream/[branch_name]
```

But it doesn't work. Nothing update, what's the reason? 
I follow the document from [github help](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/)

Comment: Did you get an indication that anything came down from the upstream?  It should look like:   `37b8a40..60d5d8f  branch_name    -> upstream/branch_name`  If you didn't get something that looks like that, nothing came down, and thus, there's nothing to merge.  Start over and capture all the commands and output so people can have the necessary information to help.

Comment: you dont need to add the "upstream" remote, it's automatically added as "master"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ git remote add upstream [remoteRepo]
$ git fetch upstream
$ git fetch upstream 
$ git merge upstream/[myBranch]
```

You haven't made any local changes yet. You're already up to date with the remote repo, so there's nothing else to do.

Comment: the [remoteRepo] has changed, so I want to update my repo also.

Comment: When you type "git fetch upstream" and subsequently merge, you've already done that. Your repo is simply "fast forwarded" to upstream repo.

Comment: Given the steps you gave above, that shouldn't have happened. You need to be more specific about precisely what you did. Start from a fresh repo and see if you can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question. If you want to change the location of the remote repository, you can go into the .git folder and open the config file and change your remote.

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@remote.com:folder/git_location.git
```

There are also commands to change a remote from the command line.
[github help - git remotes](http://help.github.com/remotes/)

Comment: actually I fork the [remoteRepo], and I want to sync with the remoteRepo due to it changed.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it didn't work?  Try 'git log' to confirm the automatic merge commit message and 'git diff HEAD^' to see what the merge did.  Also you could slightly simplify the original merge as 'git pull upstream myBranch'.

[edit]

It works for me.  Here is a complete log below.  To diagnose your problem - when you did 'git fetch' you should see something that confirms the fetch.  After the 'remote add', does 'git branch -a' list the remote branches?  You can also run 'git remote show upstream' to confirm that your repository is 'connected' to the other.  You are pulling from the repository that you cloned; other people are pulling from it; did they push their work back into it?  Otherwise you won't see their changes.

A log:

```
$ git clone dev1 -b br1 dev2
Cloning into 'dev2'...
done.
$ cd dev2
$ git remote add upstream ../dev1
$ git branch -a
* br1
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/br1
  remotes/origin/master

# NOW change content in the 'dev1' (the remote repository)
$ cd ../dev1
$ git checkout br1
Switched to branch 'br1'
$ ls
bar.c   foo.c

$ FL='baz.c'; echo "stuff" > $FL; git add $FL; git commit -m "$FL"
[br1 ef45921] baz.c
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 baz.c
$ ls
bar.c   baz.c   foo.c

 # Now return to 'dev2' and 'pull'

$ cd ../dev2
$ ls
bar.c   foo.c

$ git pull upstream
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
From ../dev1
 * [new branch]      br1        -> upstream/br1
 * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master
You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
$ git pull upstream br1
From ../dev1
 * branch            br1        -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 207c1a2..ef45921
Fast-forward
 baz.c |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 baz.c

 # Confirm 'baz.c' exists on 'dev2'
$ ls
bar.c   baz.c   foo.c
```

Comment: coz I checked one modified file in [remoteRepo], it changed, but my repo in github doesn't change, and the files in my local repo also don't change.

Comment: I'm confused about what repositories you have, which repo is fetching from which, and what repo has changes.  Can you clarify? [From your above comment, it sounds like you have a local repo, a remote repo and a github repo.]

Answer (score 0):

look at the list of branches with `git branch`

checkout the branch you want to merge the changes to with `git checkout <mainbranch>`

merge the branches with `git merge <theotherbranch>`

and push the changes

Comment: yes, I did. I just have only one branch. and I did git checkout, and git merge upstream/[myBranch]. Still nothing update. thanks

Comment: Sorry, i forgot something, try 'git branch -a' to see all local and remote branches, you need to merge the remove branch named "remote/branch_name" with your local branch "branch_name". Using just "git pull" should do it too, it's a 'git fetch' and 'git merge' all in one.